# Automatically unwrap variable when using the addition assignment operator

Tags: swift

In Swift you have the concept of Optionals data type, which you have to unwrap when you want to use them like so:

```
var myVar: String? = "Hello"
myVar = myVar! + " world!"
```

This is fine, but if you want to use the more concise addition assignment operator (+=) it seems to quickly become impossible:

```
myVar += " world!"
```

Of course this throws an error because you can't simply add a String? and a String. So is there someway to unwrap an optional value when using this operator, or does swift make you write it out the longer way?

(I imagined in a perfect world the syntax would look something like:

```
myVar +=! " world!"
```

)

**Edit:**
In this example the optional variable is declared by the person using it, of course in the real world you can have variables which you don't have the luxury of simply declaring differently. You can safely assume that this question is not about any situation where you may choose to not use optionals, this question is about using optionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this

```
var myVar: String? = "Hello"
myVar! += " world!"
```

---

**Edit:**

Besides I'd recommend to use non optional types as much as possible.
Just the `String` type can be easily initialized with an empty string and also be checked with the `empty` property. That avoids completely the optional dancing hassle.

Comment: Oh i had no idea you could do this, how does this work?

Comment: The variable is unwrapped and behaves like a non optional in this particular line but it's still an optional

Comment: Any other examples of how this would be used other than in this specific situation?

Comment: It's a very fundamental behavior: `print(myVar)` prints `Optional("Hello")`, `print(myVar!)` prints `"Hello"`

Comment: @JemarJones Vadian's solution works fine and his answer is perfectly valid. What will happen is for some reason the myVar will be nil (and it could happen)? your code will crash. If you are sure, that myVar will never be nil, it is easier to use non-optional type, or use "if let ...." or "guard" in that case

Comment: @vadian Yes i understand unwrapping when what you want is the value, but in your answer you use the operator on the left side of the assignment, as if the unwrapped value is somehow being assigned **to**. This is the first time i'm seeing an unwrapped value assigned to, do you maybe have a link to some reference material where this is explained?

Comment: @user3441734 I know that his answer works, i will accept it. I am simply trying to understand his answer rather than mindlessly use code that i don't understand semantically. Also, seeing as how optionals are used everywhere and may be part of any objects API, it's not really valid to simply suggest not using optionals.

Comment: An exclamation mark after an optional variable unwraps the optional temporarily. Then it's behaving as a non optional. That's all. It's described in depth in the Swift Language Guide.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this way because it seems that the value is always there:

```
var myVar: String = "Hello"
myVar = myVar + " world!"
```

Optionals data type is just trying to make it safer. You should make a choice based on your need. The most safest way is:

```
var myVar: String? = "Hello"
if let myVar = myVar {
    myVar += " world"!   
}
```

Comment: I am not really talking about a situation where we have the option to change the variables declaration, i only gave the declaration in the question so that it was unambiguous that we are dealing with an optional.

Comment: I mean, that would make no sense to use it like that. It has potential crash problem. Anyway, just one more prospective.

Comment: The whole purpose of the force unwrap operator is so that we may automatically unwrap values that we are **sure** are not nil. I don't think it's valid to just say no and not explain a language feature based on our opinion of it.